# Not getting chart data after clicking on AM chart

Tags: amcharts

I want to get chart data when i click on the bar chart.

[image]

such that when i click on blue line it will return respective year and month ie 2016 and May. Similarly if i click on yellow line it will return year and month. I tried below code, but its working when there is only one year ie either blue line or yellow line. But when I am trying the same code for multiple year graph I am unable to get the year. I tried the below code for the same :

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "chartScrollbar": {
                "graph": "g1",
                "oppositeAxis": false,
                "offset": 30,
                "scrollbarHeight": 50,
                "backgroundAlpha": 0,
                "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
                "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
                "graphFillAlpha": 0,
                "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
                "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
                "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
                "autoGridCount": true,
                "color": "#AAAAAA"
            },
            "chartCursor": {
                "pan": true,
                "valueLineEnabled": true,
                "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
                "cursorAlpha": 0,
                "valueLineAlpha": 0.2
            },
            "categoryAxis": {
                "parseDates": true,
                "dashLength": 1,
                "minorGridEnabled": true
            },
            "legend": {
                "useGraphSettings": true,
                "position": "top"
            },
            "balloon": {
                "borderThickness": 1,
                "shadowAlpha": 0
            },
            "dataProvider": res_data,
            "categoryField": "date",
            "startDuration": 1,
            "categoryAxis": {
                "gridPosition": "start"
            },
            "graphs": [
                {
                    "balloonText": "[[date]]" + ' ' + "[[year]]" + ":[[value]]",
                    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                    "id": "AmGraph-1",
                    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                    "title": res[0] + ' ' + valuetext,
                    "columnWidth": 0.5,
                    "type": viewcolumn,
                    "valueField": "value"
                },
                {
                    "balloonText": "[[date]]" + ' ' + "[[year1]]" + ":[[value1]]",
                    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                    "id": "AmGraph-2",
                    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                    "title": res[1] + ' ' + valuetext,
                    "type": viewcolumn,
                    "valueField": "value1"
                }
            ],
            "valueAxes": [
                {
                    "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                    "title": "",
                    "axisAlpha": 0
                }
            ],
            "export": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "listeners": [{
                    "event": "clickGraphItem",
                    "method": function (event) {
                        //console.log(event.item.dataContext.date);
                        alert(event.item.dataContext.date);

                    }
                }]
        });
    }
```

For this I am having the below dataset :

```
{result":[{"month":"Jan","year":"2016","totbooking":"0","nights":"0","comp_month":"Jan","year1":"2017","totbooking1":964,"nights1":"2685"},{"month":"Feb","year":"2016","totbooking":"0","nights":"0","comp_month":"Feb","year1":"2017","totbooking1":"0","nights1":"0"},{"month":"Mar","year":"2016","totbooking":"0","nights":"0","comp_month":"Mar","year1":"2017","totbooking1":"0","nights1":"0"},{"month":"Apr","year":"2016","totbooking":73,"nights":"154","comp_month":"Apr","year1":"2017","totbooking1":"0","nights1":"0"},{"month":"May","year":"2016","totbooking":240,"nights":"530","comp_month":"May","year1":"2017","totbooking1":"0","nights1":"0"},{"month":"Jun","year":"2016","totbooking":232,"nights":"544","comp_month":"Jun","year1":"2017","totbooking1":"0","nights1":"0"},{"month":"Jul","year":"2016","totbooking":224,"nights":"506","comp_month":"Jul","year1":"2017","totbooking1":"0","nights1":"0"},{"month":"Aug","year":"2016","totbooking":419,"nights":"1069","comp_month":"Aug","year1":"2017","totbooking1":"0","nights1":"0"},{"month":"Sep","year":"2016","totbooking":708,"nights":"1737","comp_month":"Sep","year1":"2017","totbooking1":"0","nights1":"0"},{"month":"Oct","year":"2016","totbooking":721,"nights":"1875","comp_month":"Oct","year1":"2017","totbooking1":"0","nights1":"0"},{"month":"Nov","year":"2016","totbooking":723,"nights":"1739","comp_month":"Nov","year1":"2017","totbooking1":"0","nights1":"0"},{"month":"Dec","year":"2016","totbooking":723,"nights":"1682","comp_month":"Dec","year1":"2017","totbooking1":"0","nights1":"0"}]}
```

Please go through the chart attached and respond accordingly.

Thank You

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that uses your dataset? Your chart config doesn't match the fields in your data. Also note that [dataContext](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/GraphDataItem#dataContext) uses the original item in the dataProvider array, so if you don't have a resulting "date" field after you process your code, event.item.dataContext.date won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your time @xorspark Please see the below fiddle url. Here you can see I am getting the month but not the year.  https://jsfiddle.net/abhranil/ugsg6hbx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the [`dataContext`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/GraphDataItem#dataContext) property in the [`clickGraphItem` event](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#clickGraphItem) contains the array element from the original dataProvider array. If you need to access the year, just reference it by name. Since your graphs plot specific information for their own year, use the graph's id or any other identifier to determine which year property you need to access:

```
"event": "clickGraphItem",
"method": function(event) {
  if (event.graph.id == "AmGraph-1") {
    alert(event.item.dataContext.month + ' ' + event.item.dataContext.year);
  }
  else {
    alert(event.item.dataContext.month + ' ' + event.item.dataContext.year2);
  }
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugsg6hbx/1/)